# SQL - add sequential counter column starting at condition

Tags: t-sql

I have a table:

```
  id   market
  1    mkt1
  2    mkt2
  3    mkt1
  4    special
  5    mkt2
  6    mkt2
  7    special
```

How can I select all columns from the table while also adding a sequential counter column, which starts counting once a condition has been triggered? In this example, when `market=="special"`:

```
 id   market  count
 1    mkt1     0
 2    mkt2     0
 3    mkt1     0
 4    special  1
 5    mkt2     2
 6    mkt2     3
 7    special  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `row_number` with `union all`:

```
with cte as (
  select min(id) as id from t where market = 'special'
)
select t.id, t.market, 0 rn
from t join cte on t.id < cte.id
union all
select t.id, t.market, row_number() over (order by t.id) rn
from t join cte on t.id >= cte.id
```

- [Online Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04fb9/1)

Edited to use `min` after your edits...

Comment: I have made a slight change to my question - can you perhaps update the online demo please? Thank you!

Comment: @JohnF -- Just saw your edit.  You can use `min` in the cte instead to get the first instance of the condition.

Comment: Another one here if you're interested! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57905533/sql-add-sequential-counter-column-starting-at-condition-with-group-by-and-non

Comment: @JohnF I added an answer to it as well that uses this same approach.  With that said, looks like the other answer works as well.  Hope both help!