# SQL - add sequential counter column starting at condition, with group by and non incrementing IDs

Tags: t-sql

Trickier version of this question:
[SQL - add sequential counter column starting at condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897292/sql-add-sequential-counter-column-starting-at-condition)

I have a table:

```
create table t (id int, category varchar(4), time1 datetime, market varchar(100));
insert into t (id,category,time1, market) values 
  (1000, 'cat1', '20120618 10:14:09 AM',   'mkt1'), 
  (1002, 'cat1', '20120618 10:14:11 AM',   'mkt2'), 
  (1001, 'cat2', '20120618 10:14:14 AM',  'mkt1'), 
  (1004, 'cat2', '20120618 10:14:15 AM',   'special'), 
  (1003, 'cat2', '20120618 10:14:17 AM',   'mkt2'), 
  (1006, 'cat1', '20120618 10:14:54 AM',   'special'), 
  (1007, 'cat3',  '20120618 10:14:55 AM',  'special'), 
  (1054, 'cat1', '20120618 10:14:58 AM',   'mkt1'), 
  (1023, 'cat1', '20120618 10:14:59 AM',   'mkt2'), 
  (1008, 'cat4', '20120618 10:24:09 AM',  'mkt1'), 
  (1028, 'cat2', '20120618 10:24:10 AM',   'special'), 
  (1021, 'cat1', '20120618 10:24:29 AM',   'mkt2'), 
  (1017, 'cat1', '20120618 10:34:49 AM',   'mkt2'), 
  (1019, 'cat1',  '20120618 10:34:57 AM',  'special')
```

How can I select all columns from the table while also adding a sequential counter column, which starts counting once a condition has been triggered (in this case `market='special'`), grouped by `category` and with an `id` column that is not necessarily incremental?

The result should look like:

```
id    category  time1                  market  count
1000  cat1      20120618 10:14:09 AM   mkt1    0
1002  cat1      20120618 10:14:11 AM   mkt2    0
1001  cat2      20120618 10:14:14 AM   mkt1    0
1004  cat2      20120618 10:14:15 AM   special 1
1003  cat2      20120618 10:14:17 AM   mkt2    2
1006  cat1      20120618 10:14:54 AM   special 1
1007  cat3      20120618 10:14:55 AM   special 1
1054  cat1      20120618 10:14:58 AM   mkt1    2
1023  cat1      20120618 10:14:59 AM   mkt2    3
1008  cat4      20120618 10:24:09 AM   mkt1    0
1028  cat2      20120618 10:24:10 AM   special 3
1021  cat1      20120618 10:24:29 AM   mkt2    4
1017  cat1      20120618 10:34:49 AM   mkt2    5
1019  cat1      20120618 10:34:57 AM   special 6
```

Comment: What is the condition? Why does the `count` column have those values? I assume the two duplicate rows are a typo but why do 1000,1001 and 1002 all have the same value?

Comment: Condition clarified and typo removed. Each row is a separate entry with unique `id` which may or may not have the same values for the other columns. `count` should be a sequential counter for each `category` which is 0 until the condition `market='special'` is met and 1,2,3,.... afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first it generate the `cnt` by `category`

then it find the `cnt`  for `special` by category

the final `count` is just subtract the `cnt` with  `cnt` of `special`

```
;with 
cte as 
(
    select  t.id, t.category, t.market, t.time1, 
            cnt = row_number() over (partition by t.category order by t.time1)
    from    t 
),
special as
(
    select  category, cnt = min(cnt)
    from    cte
    where   market  = 'special'
    group by category
)
select  c.id, c.category, c.market, c.time1, 
        [count]     = case  when    c.cnt < s.cnt 
                            or      s.cnt is null 
                            then    0 
                            else    c.cnt - s.cnt + 1 
                            end
from    cte c
        left join special s on  c.category  = s.category
order by time1
```

Note : `left join special` is used as there are some `category` without `special`

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow-up on my previous answer, you can still use the same approach with a few modifications.

```
with cte as (
   select min(case when market = 'special' then time1 end) time1, category 
   from t group by category
)
select t.id, t.category, t.time1, t.market, 0 
from t join cte on t.time1 < coalesce(cte.time1, '12/31/9999') 
               and t.category = cte.category
union all
select t.id, t.category, t.time1, t.market, 
    row_number() over (partition by t.category order by t.time1)
from t join cte on t.time1 >= coalesce(cte.time1, '12/31/9999') 
               and t.category = cte.category
order by time1
```

- [More Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7e49a/1)

This uses `conditional aggregation` to get the `min` time1 associated with each category, returning `null` for `cat4` since it doesn't have a record with `special`.  Then it uses `coalesce` in the `join` to use the maximum allowed value for a datetime, `12/31/9999`, to ensure categories without a record with `special` always show up with `0` counts.

Answer (score 0):

this was a fun challenge:

```
SELECT  
    id
    ,category
    ,time1
    ,market
    ,isnull(sum(tracker) over (partition by category order by time1 rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 0) as [count]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id
        ,category
        ,time1
        ,market
        ,max(iif(market = 'special', 1, null)) over (partition by category order by time1 rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as tracker
    FROM t
) sub
order by 
    time1
```